# Am I allowed to ask a company to sign a contract?

Tags: internship, contracts, legal

I am an undergraduate student. I recently got a part-time internship in a company in Mauritius. I started the internship 3 weeks ago but I have a concern. The company has **not** created any internship contract/agreement yet. During the interview process, they just verbally informed me that they are going to pay me according to the local standards. When I asked about the contract, they told me that we will do it later. It's been 3 weeks now and the company hasn't shown any proactivity regarding creating a contract.

My plan is now creating the contract myself, leaving a blank space where the company can input the amount they are going to pay me. Then, I will come to my manager and tell him to read it, escalate it to the concerned parties(HR), fill the blank and sign if the company agrees. Is it my right to create such contract? What can be the repercussions?

Comment: Did they pay you ANY money until now? If not, it is likely you are being scammed.

Comment: I know stuff is local culture dependant and opnion from a local can be invaluable here but not signing, letting contracts verbally only is a big red flag. There are some any labor law enforcement governmental organization? I guess you can seek for a local lawyer advice

Comment: @jean exactly in the UK you normally start with just the offer letter and only sign the contract after starting work in most cases

Comment: @Neuromancer the key here is how much after. 1 day, 1 week, 3 weekss?

Comment: @jean in the Uk 2 months to get proper written details but once you have accepted the job you do have a contract based on the offer letter

Comment: Have you actually started work, and if not did they tell you an actual amount that they were going to pay you? If not then walk away from this. The only reason for not telling you an amount is that they don't want you to know until it is too late.

Comment: I didn't really work. They told me that I will go through all the department first so that I can find a place where I can really fit. Each department taught me an overall concept of their work. After I am done, they will give me a definitive position. I hope that I will get a contract at that time

Answer (score 10):

> Is it my right to create such contract?

Yes, you can do this.

> What can be the repercussions?

Probably, they will refuse to sign it and let you go.

Almost certainly, the company already has a bunch of standard contracts and they're not going to want the overhead of going into a completely personalized one with you, let alone one drafted by an intern (who, I am assuming, isn't a law intern).

If you want them to make progress on the contract, you'll be better off to bring it up with your manager again, repeatedly, and stressing that you are concerned about being in a working agreement without a contract. It's a big risk for *both* parties.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you have started work, or even if you have actually accepted the job. In any case the first item of the answer is:

> You should never ever start work, or even accept a job, until they have told you how much they are paying you.

If you have not started work I would immediately contact the company and tell them that you urgently need to know how much you will be paid, as you are considering other job offers and you would like to finalize this one as soon as possible. Do this even if you have previously indicated you accept their job. They may say you have already accepted, but they can't force you to show up and nobody is ever going to enforce a job contract where they haven't told you the pay.

If they have told you the amount they will pay you, and you have accepted it, then in most jurisdictions that constitutes a contract. Don't worry about the absence of a 'legal document' with lots of fine print.